# Android programming: hiding system bars during AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, statusbar, navigationbar

I have tried some ways shown in android developers site to hide system bars. However, when an `AlertDialog` appears, system bars also appear.

Do you have an idea to always hide system bars, even in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, this may help you:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but when an AlertDialog appears, I have system bars back.
I have searched in the Internet to find a reason, but I didn't find that.

Comment: Anyone knows why AlertDialog appears in this situation?